# I'm trying to make a lua script through Logitech GHub for GMod that rotates the players view 180 degrees and can't figure out how to do the rotation

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

Here's the code I've got. I want to find a more efficient way to do this without having to hold down the primary mouse button.

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
 
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if IsKeyLockOn("numlock" )then
        repeat    
            if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
                repeat
                    MoveMouseRelative (40,0)
                    Sleep(1)
                until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
            end                
        until not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
    end
end
```

Comment: To rotate 180 degrees you can use a loop with fixed number of iterations.  `for i=1, N do ... end`  Adjust the `N` constant by trial-and-error

Answer (score 0):

as Egor said, instead of repeat function you should use for ...

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
 
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if IsKeyLockOn("numlock" )then
            if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
                for i= 1, 60 -- 60 worked for full HD resolution as i remember (lower or upper it to get back to the exact same position when pressed twice)
                    MoveMouseRelative (127,0)
                    Sleep(1) -- you should use fastsleep(0.5) here, search for it on stackoverflow
                end
            end                
    end
end
```